# HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL & The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource

Tags: servlets, http-get, http-status-code-405

When I open my browser (Chrome) on
http://localhost:8084/Staff_Member_office_hours_management/EmailSendingServlet, then I see "service" from doService() being logged on console and my thread works correctly, however I don't see "It Works" from doGet() being logged and I get the following error in the browser:

HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

I have the following servlet:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import static java.lang.System.out;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import static org.apache.coyote.http11.Constants.a;
 
/**
 * A servlet that takes message details from user and send it as a new e-mail
 * through an SMTP server.
 *
 * @author www.codejava.net
 *
 */
@WebServlet("/EmailSendingServlet")
public class EmailSendingServlet extends HttpServlet {
    
    private String host;
    private String port;
    private String user;
    private String pass;
    private static final Random RANDOM = new SecureRandom();
    public static final int PASSWORD_LENGTH = 8;
    public static String generateRandomPassword()
  {
      // Pick from some letters that won't be easily mistaken for each
      // other. So, for example, omit o O and 0, 1 l and L.
      String letters = "abcdefghjkmnpqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHJKMNPQRSTUVWXYZ23456789+@";

      String pw = "";
      for (int i=0; i<PASSWORD_LENGTH; i++)
      {
          int index = (int)(RANDOM.nextDouble()*letters.length());
          pw += letters.substring(index, index+1);
      }
      return pw;
  }
    public void init() {
        // reads SMTP server setting from web.xml file
        ServletContext context = getServletContext();
        host = context.getInitParameter("host");
        port = context.getInitParameter("port");
        user = context.getInitParameter("user");
        pass = context.getInitParameter("pass");
        
    }
 
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("registeration.jsp");
        String recipient = request.getParameter("mail");
        String id = request.getParameter("id");
        String subject = "Temporary Password to your account";
        String content = generateRandomPassword();
 
        String resultMessage = "";
        try {
            
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                String urldb = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/staffmember";
                String userdb = "root";
                String passworddb = "";
                String Line;
                Connection Con = null;
                Statement Stmt = null;
                PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
                Con = DriverManager.getConnection(urldb, userdb, passworddb);
                Stmt = Con.createStatement();
                //out.print("mmmmmm");
                String query4 = "UPDATE student SET password = '" + content + "' WHERE id = '" + id + "';";
                preparedStatement = Con.prepareStatement(query4);
                int rows3 = preparedStatement.executeUpdate(query4);
            } catch (SQLException cnfe) {
                System.err.println("Exception: " + cnfe);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(EmailSendingServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
 
        try {
            EmailUtility.sendEmail(host, port, user, pass, recipient, subject,
                    content);
            resultMessage = "The e-mail was sent successfully";
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            resultMessage = "There were an error: " + ex.getMessage();
        } finally {
            request.setAttribute("Message", resultMessage);
            getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/Result.jsp").forward(
                    request, response);
        }
    }
   
}
```

I have another the following servlet:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import static java.lang.System.out;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

public class registeration extends HttpServlet {

   
    
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        String id = request.getParameter("id");
        String name = request.getParameter("name");
        String mail = request.getParameter("mail");
        String phone = request.getParameter("mobile");
        String password ="";
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        Connection con = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet RS = null;
        PreparedStatement pst = null;
        boolean status = true;

       
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/staffmember";
            String user = "root";
            String passworddb = "";
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, passworddb);
           
             //out.println("Registered Successfully 1");
            if (mail != null && mail.trim().length() > 0) {
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            String fetchEmail = "Select mail from student where mail=" + "'" + mail + "'";
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(fetchEmail);
             //out.println("Registered Successfully 2");
            if (!rs.next()) {
                String sql = "insert into student values('" + name + "','" + mail + "','" + phone + "','" +id + "','" + password +"')";
                status = stmt.execute(sql);
                out.println("Registered Successfully");
                response.sendRedirect("EmailSendingServlet");
                out.println("Click " + "<a href=\"login.jsp\">Here</a>" + " to signin");
                
            } else {
                out.print("<span id=\"msg\" style=\"color:red;\">" + mail + "</span>" + " is already registered. Click "
                        + " <a href=\"login.jsp\">Here</a>" + " to signin");
                

            }
        } else {
            String sql = "insert into student values('" + name + "','" + mail + "','" + phone + "' ,'" + id + "','" + password +"')";
            status = stmt.execute(sql);
            out.println("Registered Successfully");
            out.print("Click " + "<a href=\"login.jsp\">Here</a>" + " to signin");
        }
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
        out.println(e);
    } finally {
        try {
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
        }

    }
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>FileUploadPdf</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>FileUploadPdf</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Search</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>Search</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>showStaff</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>showStaff</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>makeReservation</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>makeReservation</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>canelTransaction</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>canelReservation</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>cancelReservation</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>cancelReservation</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>notification</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>notification</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>messagetostaff</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>messagetostaff</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>LoginServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>registeration</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>registeration</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>EmailSendingServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>EmailSendingServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>FileUploadPdf</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/FileUploadPdf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Search</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Search</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>showStaff</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/showStaff</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>makeReservation</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/makeReservation</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>canelTransaction</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/canelTransaction</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>cancelReservation</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/cancelReservation</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>notification</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/notification</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>messagetostaff</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/messagetostaff</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/LoginServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>registeration</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/registeration</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>tls</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>host</param-name>
        <param-value>smtp.gmail.com</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>port</param-name>
        <param-value>587</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>user</param-name>
        <param-value>mohamedmagdysoffar@gmail.com</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>pass</param-name>
        <param-value>wcfhecitqrdkfkka</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>EmailSendingServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/EmailSendingServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because you have not overriden doGet method in EmailSendingServlet. This class has overriden only doPost method. You have to move your code to doGet overridden method from doPost.

Comment: I do that give me null

Comment: Can you add here stacktrace from console for null error